# GNUPLOT 5.0 "lt -1 lt -1" unrecognized

Tags: gnuplot

I install today the new version of gnuplot v.5.0 and I try a simple test using the example taken from: hhttp://www.gnuplot.info/demo/contours.5.gnu . It should show to me the 3d function, the contours and adding the levels inside the plot.

But when I use this file.plt I obtain a problem with `textcolor lt -1 lt -1`. I had to comment it in all the lines in which I found it and this make the example ok.

Could you help me to understand why?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo script http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/contours.5.gnu simply contains an error. Instead of `textcolor lt -1 lt -1` it must be `textcolor lt -1`. I'll report that.

Use the demos in the `demo` folder which work fine.